# Set content-disposition on public file types in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I have some PDF files in a public rails folder. I want to set the response header "content-disposition" to "attachment". I know I can create a controller to read the files and set the header myself, but is there some general application wide setting that i can enable/configure?

Thanks in advance.

-JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails/Rack never sees requests to your public folder, your front end web server should handle these. Assuming you are using Apache you could use [this approach](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/06-08-2007/force-a-pdf-to-download).

Failing that you can move the files out of the way and use either a rack middleware or a controller as mentioned to handle the request.

Answer (score 2):

What cwninja said.

Assuming Apache as your front-end server:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

`application/octet-stream` because `application/pdf` doesn't force a download in IE sometimes.